# How to add KML data but from variable - not from url?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a working map that retrieves KML from a url, but now I need to get the KML data from a local variable instead.  Is there support for this, and if so what is the syntax.  Searched the api and various sites but no luck finding anything about this.  Thanks!

[Addendum]

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                {layers: "basic"}
            ),
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "kml_large.kml",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                        extractStyles: true, 
                        extractAttributes: true,
                        maxDepth: 2
                    })
                })
            })
        ],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-81, 28),
        zoom: 7
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[OpenLayers.Format.KML.read()](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.KML.read)**

This will create [OpenLayers.Feature.Vector](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html) Features from the KML string.

*You might need to modify the projection info to fit your needs:*

```
function GetFeaturesFromKMLString (strKML) {
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        'internalProjection': myMapObject.baseLayer.projection,
        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    });
    return format.read(strKML);
};
```

Then you can do something like:

```
myVectorLayer.addFeatures(GetFeaturesFromKMLString(myKMLString));
```

Comment: Ok, cool, so now I get what a Format object does, however, how would I integrate this with my current code?  Sorry to ask for hand-holding but I find the API docs for OL to be really poor... (e.g. the OpenLayers.Layer.Vector constructor does not make it clear what an Options object should be composed of) Thanks again. See code posted to my original question.

Comment: Never mind that last question, I think I get it now.

Comment: sure? let me know... or post another question :)

Comment: Needs the option extractStyles: true to pick up the styles