# Show KML from variable instead of URL

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, kml, google-earth

I am trying to add a layer from KML variable instead of URL due to the current circumstances that force me to. I am using OpenLayers 2.13.1, Chrome, Visual Studio and .NET.

I have read the following link and followed them but still unable to show the result.

[In OpenLayers can I replace a kml's URL for OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP with the actual text of the kml?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65291/in-openlayers-can-i-replace-a-kmls-url-for-openlayers-protocol-http-with-the-ac)

[How to add KML data but from variable - not from url?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16629/how-to-add-kml-data-but-from-variable-not-from-url)

[OpenLayers 2.12 + KML from String + Change markers'icons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33873/openlayers-2-12-kml-from-string-change-markersicons)

Below is my code:

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
          "OpenLayers WMS",
          "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
          { layers: 'basic' }
      );

var kml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">   <Document>     <Style id="boundaryLineColor1">       <LineStyle>         <color>ff000000</color>         <width>3</width>       </LineStyle>       <PolyStyle>         <fill>false</fill>       </PolyStyle>     </Style>     <Folder>       <name>Soybean Yield</name>       <Placemark>         <name>Soybean Yield (1)</name>         <styleUrl>#boundaryLineColor1</styleUrl>         <Polygon>           <outerBoundaryIs>             <LinearRing>               <coordinates>-91.3342663759154,32.5034766500927 -91.3342667084831,32.5034586155548 -91.3342986325171,32.5028817921232 -91.3347528643046,32.5013364566058 -91.3353490833926,32.5013263087953 -91.3371799720313,32.501314445573 -91.338116698321,32.5013087851122 -91.3386487408102,32.501315812754 -91.3386663742212,32.5015144742388 -91.3387262951512,32.5028862267216 -91.3387406121766,32.5032652339614 -91.3387805784262,32.5045645667511 -91.3389131380096,32.5089317435004 -91.3389218164796,32.5096173380048 -91.3389859320576,32.5153906443518 -91.3389832778257,32.5155349207259 -91.3388110064899,32.5156408789761 -91.337874131254,32.5156465397406 -91.3359365262234,32.5156569954422 -91.334957081528,32.5156620711925 -91.3346590909512,32.515658125708 -91.3345962338078,32.5156031766372 -91.3345799386691,32.5153323771848 -91.3345104393058,32.5133291373803 -91.3344968056745,32.5129140617432 -91.3342663759154,32.5034766500927</coordinates>             </LinearRing>           </outerBoundaryIs>         </Polygon>       </Placemark>     </Folder>   </Document> </kml>'
var kmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
    extractStyles: true,
    extractAttributes: true
}); // Initialize with options if necessary
var feature_list = kmlParser.read(kml_string);
var sundialsTest = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Test");
sundialsTest.addFeatures(feature_list);
this.application.map.map.addLayers([wms, sundialsTest]);
```

Can someone help?

I am pretty new to OpenLayers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your code. I did the same with in a simple html file and it worked. The only thing I had to change was the reference to the map.

In plain html + javascript you would reference the map simple by using the map variable.

```
map.addLayer(sundialsTest);
```

or

```
map.addLayers([sundialsTest]);
```

Make sure that `this.application.map.map`is a reference to your OpenLayers map.

```
console.log(this.application.map.map);
```

I added a screenshot with the result. To make it, I changed the base layer to Bing, and I also reproject the string.

The entire code is:

```
    var map = null;
    var apiKey = "(...)"; // your Bing API key
    function init() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        var road = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
            name: "Road",
            key: apiKey,
            type: "Road"
        });
        map.addLayers([road]);
        var kml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">   <Document>     <Style id="boundaryLineColor1">       <LineStyle>         <color>ff000000</color>         <width>3</width>       </LineStyle>       <PolyStyle>         <fill>false</fill>       </PolyStyle>     </Style>     <Folder>       <name>Soybean Yield</name>       <Placemark>         <name>Soybean Yield (1)</name>         <styleUrl>#boundaryLineColor1</styleUrl>         <Polygon>           <outerBoundaryIs>             <LinearRing>               <coordinates>-91.3342663759154,32.5034766500927 -91.3342667084831,32.5034586155548 -91.3342986325171,32.5028817921232 -91.3347528643046,32.5013364566058 -91.3353490833926,32.5013263087953 -91.3371799720313,32.501314445573 -91.338116698321,32.5013087851122 -91.3386487408102,32.501315812754 -91.3386663742212,32.5015144742388 -91.3387262951512,32.5028862267216 -91.3387406121766,32.5032652339614 -91.3387805784262,32.5045645667511 -91.3389131380096,32.5089317435004 -91.3389218164796,32.5096173380048 -91.3389859320576,32.5153906443518 -91.3389832778257,32.5155349207259 -91.3388110064899,32.5156408789761 -91.337874131254,32.5156465397406 -91.3359365262234,32.5156569954422 -91.334957081528,32.5156620711925 -91.3346590909512,32.515658125708 -91.3345962338078,32.5156031766372 -91.3345799386691,32.5153323771848 -91.3345104393058,32.5133291373803 -91.3344968056745,32.5129140617432 -91.3342663759154,32.5034766500927</coordinates>             </LinearRing>           </outerBoundaryIs>         </Polygon>       </Placemark>     </Folder>   </Document> </kml>'
        var kmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true,
            extractAttributes: true,
            internalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
            externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });
        var feature_list = kmlParser.read(kml_string);
        var sundialsTest = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Test");
        sundialsTest.addFeatures(feature_list);
        map.addLayer(sundialsTest);
        map.zoomToExtent(sundialsTest.getDataExtent());
    }
```

[image]