# Add GML Vector Layer to OpenLayers from String (Variable)

Tags: openlayers-2, vector-layer

I am trying to add a vector layer to a map, wich is working fine if included like this:

```
var gmlfeature = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
                      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "gmltest.xml",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML()
                      }),
                      strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
}) 

map.addLayer( gmlfeature );
```

I wanted to be able to upload .gml Files to the webpage, though. After parsing the GML content and reprojecting the coordinates, I would like to include the features from a string (wich has the same content as 'gmltest.xml). I tried to follow the method described [in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16629/how-to-add-kml-data-but-from-variable-not-from-url) with no luck.
Here is what I've come up with so far: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgjkmam4/), the Features seem to load but they are not projected as expected.
A sample GML [can be downloaded here](https://uni-bonn.sciebo.de/index.php/s/hmO2DzvpFv4Sstp).

Comment: Why do you have openlayers-3 as a tag, it's version 2?

Comment: @Christoph I suggest you merge your two accounts. See [this link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).